# Formatting picture in a mail message

Tags: mail.app, formatting

When writing an email, I want the picture I insert to be formatted (add shadow or border for example). How to do this ?

When right-clicking the picture, I only have basic options:
[image]

I found nothing more when looking in the menus.
Is this then even possible?

Comment: "Format" usually refers to things like placement, not things like drop shadows. As matrix says, if you want to add graphical elements you need to do that with another application. The problem with attempting to control the placement of the image in email is that the recipients may have different mail clients which may display the "formatted" email differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mail.app just attaches pictures as they are. If you want to edit the picture, you need specific software for this. iPhoto and Preview provide some basic image editing capabilities. For more functionality you may want to look at [Skitch](http://www.evernote.com/skitch/) or one of the many offerings in the App Store.